# pc3-10600s-9-10-f1 menory Or pc3-10600s-9-10-f3 memory

Tags: laptop, memory, dell-studio

Does it matter if you use pc3-10600s-9-10-f1 memory or pc3-10600s-9-10-f3 memory in my laptop? Want to upgrade from 2 slots with 2gb to 2slots with 4gb. And can’t find the 4gb pc3-10600s-9-10-f1 memory online

Answer (score 0):

The "F1" or "F3" designation is not a standard part of a DDR3 memory naming scheme that I know of. It is not denoting any speed or latency that I am aware of.

It is probably designating the version of the memory module, i.e. that there may be some minor but almost certainly inconsequential change between modules. It may be that the track layout has been improved or an obsolete part replaced or updated.

Chances are the modules will function identically.